# How can this function be vectorized?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a NumPy array with the following properties:

- shape: (9986080, 2)
- dtype: np.float32

I have a method that loops over the range of the array, performs an operation and then inputs result to new array:

```
def foo(arr):
    new_arr = np.empty(arr.size, dtype=np.uint64)
    for i in range(arr.size):
        x, y = arr[i]
        e, n = ''
        if x < 0:
            e = '1'
        else:
            w = '2'
        if y > 0:
            n = '3'
        else:
            s = '4'
        new_arr[i] = int(f'{abs(x)}{e}{abs(y){n}'.replace('.', ''))
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this code? I can see what it's literally doing but I'm not sure why you're doing it. Knowing what it's supposed to do might help lead to a better answer.

Comment: @Iguananaut It's take the X Y values that represent the center points of arbitrary shapes, determining the quadrant their latitudes and longitudes reside in and building a unique ID from that, finally converting it to an int. That conversion is needed to save on storage in the file format later.

Comment: OK that makes sense. I'm curious though what is thus file format? I don't have enough information to say whether or not this scheme is well-motivated, but it seems awfully opaque if you ask me.

Comment: @Iguananaut Proprietary unfortunately. Nevertheless, I am seeking to vectorize this or find a way to apply it across the array rather than iterate the range.

Comment: What are the domains of x and y though. If I'm not mistaken this doesn't return a unique value for any arbitrary x and y.

Comment: @Iguananaut because its geodesic coordinates, the domain is x: [-180, 180] and y: [-90, 90]. Decimal degrees to 5 degrees of precision are used for a unique array of arbitrary size, the Easting/Northing (EWNS) of a coordinate is transformed to (1234), so unique integer is (should) be guaranteed (there is never duplication in the array).

Comment: Take `11114`. Is that `(-11, 1)` or `(-1, 11)`? I'm not sure it works unless you pad each coordinate to a fixed width of digits (at least for y; for x you'll lose leading zeros when converting to an int).

Comment: @Iguananaut They are unique with 0 padded strings, sorry forgot to include. Assume the format of a point is `(lon, lat)`, then giving the mapping in the question, `(-11, 1)` is `(-11W, 1N)` which would become `0112013`; whereas `(-1, 11)` is `(-1W, 11N)` which would become `0012113`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Iguananaut's comment that this data structure seems a bit odd. My biggest problem with it is that it is really tricky to try and vectorize the putting together of integers in a string and then re-converting that to an integer. Still, this will certainly help speed up the function:

```
def foo(arr):
    x_values = arr[:,0]
    y_values = arr[:,1]
    ones = np.ones(arr.shape[0], dtype=np.uint64)
    e = np.char.array(np.where(x_values < 0, ones, ones * 2))
    n = np.char.array(np.where(y_values < 0, ones * 3, ones * 4))
    x_values = np.char.array(np.absolute(x_values))
    y_values = np.char.array(np.absolute(y_values))
    x_values = np.char.replace(x_values, '.', '')
    y_values = np.char.replace(y_values, '.', '')
    new_arr = np.char.add(np.char.add(x_values, e), np.char.add(y_values, n))
    return new_arr.astype(np.uint64)
```

Here, the x and y values of the input array are first split up. Then we use a vectorized computation to determine where `e` and `n` should be 1 or 2, 3 or 4. The last line uses a standard list comprehension to do the string merging bit, which is still undesirably slow for super large arrays but faster than a regular for loop. Also vectorizing the previous computations should speed the function up hugely.

**Edit:**
I was mistaken before. Numpy does have a nice way of handling string concatenation using the np.char.add() method. This requires converting `x_values` and `y_values` to Numpy character arrays using `np.char.array()`. Also for some reason, the `np.char.add()` method only takes two arrays as inputs, so it is necessary to first concatenate `x_values` and `e` and `y_values` and `n` and then concatenate these results. Still, this vectorizes the computations and should be pretty fast. The code is still a bit clunky because of the rather odd operation you are after, but I think this will help you speed up the function greatly.

Comment: Suppose you kept it as an array of strings, would there be a faster way to specify the number of bytes needed per string and assign the string value to each element of the array?

Comment: Looked into this question and found a better way to do it. See my update above. I think this accomplishes what you wanted to do pretty efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `np.apply_along_axis`. When you feed this function with another function that takes **row (or column)** as an argument, it does what you want to do.

For you case, You may rewrite the function as below:

```
def foo(row):
        x, y = row
        e, n = ''
        if x < 0:
            e = '1'
        else:
            w = '2'
        if y > 0:
            n = '3'
        else:
            s = '4'
        return int(f'{abs(x)}{e}{abs(y){n}'.replace('.', ''))


# Where you want to you use it.
new_arr = np.apply_along_axis(foo, 1, n)
```